# if Statement, not working as expected when checking length of column in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I want to only update the size of a column, if it's currently smaller than my desired size. This statement below makes sense to me, but when I run it...it's coming out that an alter would occur. Why is @len < 255? I can verify that the column in question is actually 255.

I can also verify that 'select @len - 1' comes out to 254.

```
DECLARE @len int

SET @len = (select Cast(character_maximum_length As int) 
           from information_schema.columns  
           where table_name = 'myTable'
           And column_name = 'myCol')

IF (@len < 255)
    BEGIN
        Print 'No work.'
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
         Print 'Alter table myTable Alter Column myCol varchar (255)'
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have swapped the condition. You would change the field if the length is smaller than 255:

```
IF (@len < 255)
BEGIN
    Print 'Alter table myTable Alter Column myCol varchar (255)'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Print 'No work.'
END
```